# sssd cache issues with authorized_keys

Tags: centos7, ssh-keys, sssd

I'm running a server with CentOS 7.4.1708 and all patches applied. sssd is version 1.15.2.

I have a working sssd setup which enables me to sign in using SSH public keys stored in Active Directory.

**The config**

The instance is successfully joined and this is my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
domains = EXAMPLE.COM
default_domain_suffix = EXAMPLE.COM
config_file_version = 2
debug_level = 7
services = nss, pam, ssh

[domain/EXAMPLE.COM]
ad_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
debug_level = 7
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = sshPublicKey
ad_access_filter = DOM:EXAMPLE.COM:(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=ACL_DEV_APAC_developers,OU=ACL,OU=Group,OU=EXAMPLE,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM)

[ssh]
debug_level = 7

[nss]
debug_level = 7
```

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` includes

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

**The problem**

User are able to log in only once during cache lifetime (by default 90 minutes), otherwise they are denied access. See the log at https://pastebin.com/Jqc52MWH. For logs with `debug_level = 9` see https://pastebin.com/0uQ8MCuS

Running `sss_ssh_authorizedkeys myadmin` works perfectly when run with a clean/timed-out cache (even multiple times in a row). When I log in via ssh and try to run it directly after then nothing is returned for the user logged in but I can query a (new/fresh) user right away.

**The workaround**

adding `entry_cache_user_timeout = 5` to `[domain/EXAMPLE.COM]` in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` enables a login every 5 seconds. Faster logins are not possible. A lower timeout lengthens the login time.

**Solution**

Anyone a solution to this problem?

Comment: Tested with 1.15.3. No change. Did test with 1.13.4, no issue

Comment: Is ldap service discovery working? Are all nodes accessable? Try adding `debug_level = 9`

Comment: added `debug_level = 9` to everything. I cannot find anything more specific in the log: https://pastebin.com/0uQ8MCuS

Comment: What do you AD groups look like? How many? Nested?

Comment: Nested, in total around 30. But: *First login works*

Comment: Opened a ticket at sssd issue tracker: https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See bug report for latest status - https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3534

---

**Workaround 1**

Adding the ldap attribute sshPublicKey to the global catalog solves the issue. See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2015/02/28/ad-ds-global-catalogs-and-the-partial-attribute-set/ for instructions. The attribute should look something like this: [image: schema settings]

**Workaround 2**

Alternatively one can add `ad_enable_gc = false` to the domain config. Then the global catalog will only be used for cross-domain group memberships. See `man sssd-ad` for details.